# Data Form reset is not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Written code to save the data and reset the data. In this case data is saving successfully but unable to make reset the form. When i click on pencil icon it turn to floppy disk and remove icon. If i click on floppy disk data is saving but when i click on remove icon data form is not being reset. I tried code this way

```js
//Banking details form validation
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editBankDetailBtn').click(function() {
    if ($('.editBankDetail').is('[readonly]')) { //checks if it is already on readonly mode
      $('.editBankDetail').prop('readonly', false); //turns the readonly off
      $('.editBankDetailBtn').html(
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk">&nbsp;</span>' +
        '<span id="reset-form" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">&nbsp;</span>');
      //  $('.glyphicon-remove')[0].reset();

    } else { //else we do other things

      var patt = /^([0-9]{11})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/;
      var reg = /^[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6,7}$/;
      patt.test('acdbdfdsfsf22-333-666666'); // true

      var bname_1 = document.getElementById('name').value;

      if (bname_1 == "") {

        document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
      }

      $('.editBankDetail').prop('readonly', true);
      $('.editBankDetailBtn').html(
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>');
      $('.glyphicon-remove').on('click', function() {
        $("#reset-form").trigger("reset");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <span style="font-weight: 700;">Banking Details</span> &nbsp; <a class="editBankDetailBtn"><span
               class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span></a>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="pls" style="color: darkred">&nbsp;</span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Bank
                     Name<span style="color: red;">*</span>
                     </label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control editBankDetail" id="bankName" readonly placeholder="Bank Name" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Account
                     Number<span style="color: red;">*</span>
                     </label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control editBankDetail" id="accountNumber" readonly placeholder="Account Number" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">IFSC
                     CODE<span style="color: red;">*</span>
                     </label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control editBankDetail" id="ifscCode" readonly placeholder="IFSC CODE" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-8">Bank
                     Address<span style="color: red;">*</span>
                     </label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea class="form-control editBankDetail" id="branchAddress" placeholder="Bank Address" readonly> </textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!----Ends second column-------->
</div>
</div>
<!----Ends accordion column-------->
</div>
```

Comment: @Learning - A JSfiddle/CodePen would be appreciated and will get you answers much quickly

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Not needed - even quicker is a StackSnippet

Comment: @mplungjan yes true, but with jsfiddle, i don't even need to copy the code from stack snippet to test it out myself.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal What do you mean? You just click "copy snippet to answer" and you can test all you want. You  even get the console right there

Comment: @mplungjan oh! That I didn't know. Thanks :)

Comment: The `$('.glyphicon-remove')` click event is inside another event. Use delegation and put it outside the parent `click` event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several things

- You need to reset a form, not an icon like you do now
- PLEASE have a toggleClass on the bankName - it is not `name`, but `bankName` in your code
- You need to delegate - something like this - the element that gets the event handler has to be static in the page and exist at the time of delegation, here `$('.editBankDetailBtn')`

---

```
$('.editBankDetailBtn').on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function() {
  $("#myForm")[0].reset()
});
```

Comment: I tried this before posting code here but didn't work.

Comment: @Learning Did you make it work and then accepted my answer or does it still not work?

Comment: I followed the method which mentioned by you.

Answer (score 0):

Your click will not work on the ones created dynamically. Add below code

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function() {
  // Put one alert or console to check that you here
    $("#YOU_FORM_ID")[0].reset(); //
});
```

Comment: This is the same answer I gave.